# Error installing nokogiri: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extensions

Tags: ruby, rvm, rails

I can build my rails application on my mac

On my Ubuntu machine when I `bundle` I get errors with a bunch of gems including nokogiri, version 1.6.7.2

Error installing nokogiri: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extensions

I try `gem install nokogiri -v1.6.7.2`  but I still get the error.

I am using rvm and ruby 2.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key library here was `libgmp-dev`, installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

possibly due to my use of RVM to manage my ruby versions.

Once done, nokogiri and all the other failing gems were able to be installed (mostl easily just with `bundle`).

The other gems that had been failing were:

```
bcrypt-ruby 3.0.1
hitimes 1.2.3
ffi 1.9.10
eventmachine 1.0.7
geoip-c 0.8.1
mysql2 0.3.20
```

but after the nokogiri install they all installed with `bundle`

Comment: or you could just install the ruby-nokogiri package (with versions ranging from 1.5.0-1 in precise to 1.6.7.2-3build1 in xenial - see http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nokogiri+&searchon=sourcenames ).  bundling code that is available in a distro package is **always** a bad idea.  instead, make a package of your code that depends on other packages....and if a particular ruby gem (or whatever) doesn't exist as a package, make a separate package of that rather than bundle it with your code.

Comment: BTW, **ALL** of the ruby gems you mention except for `geoip-c` are available pre-packaged for Ubuntu....and `geoip-c`'s dependencies (`minitest` and `rake`) are both available as packages for ubuntu, so building a `ruby-geoip-c` package should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 2):

**If the above answer doesnt work try this**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
```

**then install Nokogiri**

```
gem install nokogiri
```